# Cannot get ansible to recognize group variables

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set up environment specific variables in ansible (e.g. production, staging, development). For some reason, ansible is not picking up variables in group_vars/[environment].

I'm using ansible 1.9.1

Here's a stripped down example of what I'm trying to do.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── staging
├── hosts
│   └── staging
└── site.yml
```

group_vars/staging:

```
test_var: "this is a test"
```

site.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="test variable = {{ test_var }}"
```

hosts/staging is an empty file

Output of running `ansible-playbook -i hosts/staging site.yml`:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug msg="test variable = {{ test_var }}"] ****************************
fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'test_var' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/jcowley/site.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

If I move group_vars/staging to group_vars/all, it works as expected and outputs the value of test_var. But I'm trying to understand how I can separate environments per the documentation in Ansible's [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#how-to-differentiate-stage-vs-production)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

To answer your question more specifically, please have a look at [this github exemple](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/tree/master/lamp_simple) project. This is, I think, what you tried to do.
I might be wrong, but I think the problem comes from your inventory file. You actually named your `group_vars` files (`staging`) after your inventory filename (`staging` too).
But, you must name it after the **section** inside your inventory file, which is, I suppose, `localhost` looking at your playbook.

Thus, this is what you should have:

*hosts/staging*:

```
[staging]
X.X.X.X
```

Here is, according to me, a more viable solution to organize your project. It is based on [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html).

Directory structure:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   └── all
├── hosts
│   └── local
│   └── staging
│   └── prod
├── roles
│   └── exemple
│       └── tasks
│       └── vars
│           └── local.yml
│           └── staging.yml
│           └── prod.yml
└── site.yml
```

The `group_vars/all` could have an env variable:

```
# The application environment
# Possible values are : prod, staging or local
env: local

# Other global variables
...
```

Your inventory file:

```
[local]
X.X.X.X

[staging]
X.X.X.X

[prod]
X.X.X.X
```

Then, your playbook `sites.yml` could look like this:

```
---
- name: Server(s) configuration
  hosts: "{{env}}"
  roles:
    - exemple
  vars_files:
    - "roles/example/vars/{{env}}.yml"
```

Doing it this way gives you multiple benefits:

- you can reuse the env variable anywhere in your project, in jinja templates or as a condition in tasks which is very practical;
- your project is split into separate roles. It’s cleaner this way for big project (you can have an apache role, ssh role, etc.);
- you can create env-specific variables in separate files in `roles/exemple/vars/` directory.

Comment: Thanks @gui-don. That looks like a viable workaround.


I would still like to understand why my example does not function, though. As far as I can tell, that is exactly how it is supposed to be done per the Ansible docs and numerous examples I've found online.


Would like to understand if there is an error that I'm not seeing in my example.

Comment: Again, appreciate the suggested workaround. But I'd like to know why the standard directory structure with group_vars/staging is not working. Use of an environment variable should not be required, nor should explicitly loading the variables via a 'var_files' directive. Here's an example that is set up like mine https://github.com/roots/bedrock-ansible. There are tons of others out there. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jason Cowley Sure. As I said in my answer, did you check your inventory file to contain a section named after your `group_vars` file?

Comment: Ah, okay. That's it. The hosts/staging file needs to have [staging] defined. Thank you!